# SSRS Error, Invalid Sheet name

Tags: ssrs-2008-r2

I have a report that creates multiple tabs will export to Excel grouping on the account number, all of a sudden on export it tells I Have an Invalid Sheet name and creates something weird on sheet 212.
Please help. accounting is on me. Not SSRS developer.

James

Answer (score 0):

Excel has limitations on sheet names.

A sheet name must be 31 characters or less.

It cannot have any invalid characters: `/ \ * [ ] : ?`

It also cannot start or end with a single quote (`'`).

And the Sheet Name cannot be empty/NULL.

And cannot be named **History**:

[image]

If your page names are derived from the **Account Number** or some other field, check that field for the invalid characters above or if there is a blank.

[image]

Comment: The export to excel has been working for over a year, this new tab and invalid sheet name just started. I looked for a limitation of a page size and haven't found anything.

Comment: Are your sheet names based on a field from a table (like **Account Number**)? There may have been a new value added to the table that has an invalid character (or too many characters). What's the **weird** thing on sheet 212?

Comment: The tabs are grouped by Region, This one is Mid-Atlantic. Instead of added the row to the tab, it is creating sheet 212.

Comment: The tabs are grouped by Region, This one is Mid-Atlantic. Instead of added the row to the tab, it is creating sheet 212.